# How to listen for property collection size changes

Tags: qt, qml

I want to automatically show/hide view depending on a property's collection size, here's the code:

```
QtObject {
    property var controlWindow: Window {
        property var collection: []

        signal sigAddElement(var element)
        onSigAddElement: {
            collection.push(element)
        }

        signal sigEraseAllElements()
        onSigEraseAllElements: {
            collection.length = 0
        }

        onCollectionChanged: {
            console.log("collection.len = " + collection.length)
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: autoHidableView
            visible: collection.length != 0
        }
    }
}
```

but `visible` property of `autoHidableView` evaluates only once on startup and never evaluates again
The `onCollectionChanged` handler is never get called which is understandable since collection object itself stays the same
**So is it possible to listen for collection's size change event?**

Comment: I get a warning that `collection is not defined` on the `visible` property of `Rectangle`, so that might be why it's not working. Also, why do you wrap it in a QtObject?

Comment: @Amfasis, it's a legacy code and I got rid of all irrelevant parts, but I wasn't sure if `QtObject` and `Window` were relevant so I saved them. Did you work out why you were getting a `undefined` warning?

Comment: I didn't look into the `undefined`, but maybe it works when referencing `controlWindow.collection.count`?

Comment: @Amfasis, that's just a mock code, no need it to be compilable. But the error seems interesting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the javascript array that you create with `property var collection: []` does not have any signals (the `onCollectionChanged` is indeed when you would assign a new collection to it). You better use ListModel:

```
QtObject {
    property var controlWindow: Window {

        ListModel {
            id: collection
        }

        signal sigAddElement(var element)
        onSigAddElement: {
            collection.append(element)
        }

        signal sigEraseAllElements()
        onSigEraseAllElements: {
            collection.clear()
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: autoHidableView
            visible: collection.count > 0
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you need to change the `push` to `append`

Comment: thanks for your answer, please replace `collection.length = 0` with `collection.clear()` so that it would be a working solution

Comment: thanks for spotting that, I mainly focused on adding ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Listening to the array length is not enough.
See [var QML Basic Type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-var.html#change-notification-semantics):

> It is important to note that changes in regular properties of JavaScript objects assigned to a var property will **not** trigger updates of bindings that access them.

It is the same behavior when assigning an array to the var. The binding will only be reevaluated if the property is reassigned with an entire new object/array.

You have 2 ways to make your binding listen to the collection length change:

- Reassign the entire array:

  ```
  onSigAddElement: {
      collection = collection.concat(element)
  }
  // ...
  onSigEraseAllElements: {
      collection = []
  }
  ```
- Trigger the change signal manually:

  ```
  onSigAddElement: {
      collection.push(element)
      collectionChanged()
  }
  // ...
  onSigEraseAllElements: {
      collection.length = 0
      collectionChanged()
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the first option doesn't force reevaluation of `visible` property of `autoHidableView`. The second one is my initial option which I wanted to simplify

Comment: I successfully tested both options, are you sure your `Rectangle` is not actually visible but hidden by an other component and/or without width/height? Do you have a log when you print `onVisibleChanged`on the Rectangle ?

Comment: I tested only `onSigEraseAllElements` handler, I'll look into it

Comment: Yeah, I also had to set a width+height+color when testing ;-) next to unwrapping it from the `QtObject`